# In mongodb is mapReduce with single key is faster than mapReduce with 2 or 3 keys?

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, key

In mongodb is mapReduce with single key is faster than mapReduce with 2 or 3 keys?
I have this doubt because anyhow we need O(n) to map them where n is the size of collection

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean mapReduce with multiple emits, or mapReduce with a compound key like { x : 1, y : 1 }?  Emitting multiple keys per doc can make the reduce phase somewhat longer, since there is more data to combine.  A compound emitted key would make the emitted data larger, so there would be storage (and network) overhead.

Comment: I mean mapReducing with multiple Keys. My doubt is that whether  map=function(){var key={name:this.name, num:this.num}; emit(key,{count:1}); } is slower than map=function(){var key={name:this.name}; emit(key,{count:1}); }